# How to output a comma delimited list in jinja python template?

Tags: python, jinja2

If I have a list of `users` say `["Sam", "Bob", "Joe"]`, I want to do something where I can output in my jinja template file:

```
{% for user in userlist %}
    <a href="/profile/{{ user }}/">{{ user }}</a>
    {% if !loop.last %}
        , 
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I want to make the output template be:

```
Sam, Bob, Joe
```

I tried the above code to check if it was on the last iteration of the loop and if not, then don't insert a comma, but it does not work. How do I do this?

Comment: jinja, like Python, does not use `!` as a negation operator. "not" is spelled "not".

Answer (score 459, accepted):

You want your `if` check to be:

```
{% if not loop.last %}
    ,
{% endif %}
```

Note that you can also shorten the code by using [If Expression](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/templates/#if-expression):

```
{{ ", " if not loop.last else "" }}
```

Comment: Just fyi, you might need to make this an if/else based on your settings. More info. can be found here: https://github.com/pallets/jinja/issues/710

Comment: or is some cases `{{ "," if not forloop.last }}`

Comment: I second the comment about adding an else. This worked for me `{{ "," if not loop.last else "" }}`

Comment: In my case it was `forloop` instead of `loop` and `{%` instead of `{{`, like this: `{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}`. Other solutions did not work

Comment: or even shorter: `{{ "" if loop.last else ", " }}`

Answer (score 291):

You could also use the builtin [`join`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.join) filter like this:

```
{{ users|join(', ') }}
```

Comment: While this works for creating a csv, seeing his example above, it can't be used with the surrounding anchor.

Comment: This approach also doesn't work well with escaping:
['{{ ['a\'', 'b']|join("', '") }}']
produces
['a&#39;&#39;, &#39;b']

Comment: This should be the first thing attempted. If it doesn't work as desired, then try another solution, but this is definitely cleanest.

Comment: This gives a trailing comma, how do I get rid of that?

Comment: You probably have an trailing empty element. If you've got three elements a b c you will get aXbXc when joining with X: `ansible -i localhost, all -m debug -a "msg=\"{{ [ 'a','b','c' ]|join('X') }}\""`

Comment: This doesn't work for IP sets, it'll output much garbage:

`"1, 9, 2, ., 1, 6, 8, ., 3, 3, ., 1, 0"`

Comment: This works if you do not need separate spans/formatting/links on the inner items.

Answer (score 84):

And using the `joiner` from https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/templates/#joiner

```
{% set comma = joiner(",") %}
{% for user in userlist %}
    {{ comma() }}<a href="/profile/{{ user }}/">{{ user }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

It's made for this exact purpose. Normally a join or a check of forloop.last would suffice for a single list, but for multiple groups of things it's useful.

A more complex example on why you would use it.

```
{% set pipe = joiner("|") %}
{% if categories %} {{ pipe() }}
    Categories: {{ categories|join(", ") }}
{% endif %}
{% if author %} {{ pipe() }}
    Author: {{ author() }}
{% endif %}
{% if can_edit %} {{ pipe() }}
    <a href="?action=edit">Edit</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This actually worked pretty well for me, without leaving a trailing comma. Thanks for this one!