# Comma Separating List Values in a Jinja template

Tags: python, jinja2

I'm using a for loop to create a list like `[1, 2, 3]`. Here's my Jinja template, which produce some Javascript:

```
xAxis: {
                categories: {
                    [
                    {% for data in records['result'] %}
                        {{ data['_id']['day'] }},
                    {% endfor %}
                ]
            },
```

It runs fine and generates the expected result, but my IDE (PyCharm) complains that the final comma is unnecessary (it isn't): `[1,2,3,]` instead of `[1,2,3]`.

Is there a better way to place a comma at end end (e.g. convert to string first and concatenate the comma to the end)? Or, should I ignore the warning?

Comment: Please, do mind, that others do not have the context of your problem in their heads as you do and pay attention to details. What is your code? Is is definitely not Python, it looks like some jinja2 or Django template, but a bit strange.

Comment: i would use a the `join` filter rather than a loop for this

Comment: Is this not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11974318/how-to-output-a-comma-delimited-list-in-jinja-python-template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Jinja (it seems to be the case), you can use [the `join` filter directly](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#join):

```
xAxis: {
            categories: {
                [{{ records['result']|join(', ', attribute='_id.day') }}]
        },
```

The `attribute` syntax allows to get subkey by separating them with a dot, [according to the source code](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/jinja2/blob/master/jinja2/filters.py#L54).

Comment: Perfect! Works great -- didn't know about `attribute`. Thanks! :)

Comment: If I want to join attributes `_id.month` and `_id.day` to generate a list like `[1/1, 1/2]`, how come I can't do this? `[{{ records['result']|join(', ', join(attribute='_id.month', attribute='_id.day')) }}]`

Comment: You can't do it "simply" with templates. You should review your `records` data structure to include a way to get the `_id.day+"/"+id._month` directly.