# Jinja2 template variables to one line

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Is it possible to create a jinja2 template that puts variables on one line?  Something like this but instead of having two lines in the results have them comma separated.

**Template:**

```
{% for host in groups['tag_Function_logdb'] %}
elasticsearch_discovery_zen_ping_unicast_hosts = {{ host }}:9300
{% endfor %}
```

**Results:**

```
elasticsearch_discovery_zen_ping_unicast_hosts = 1.1.1.1:9300
elasticsearch_discovery_zen_ping_unicast_hosts = 2.2.2.2:9300
```

**Desired Results:**

```
elasticsearch_discovery_zen_ping_unicast_hosts = 1.1.1.1:9300,2.2.2.2:9300
```

**Edit, this works for 2 items, better solution below:**

```
elasticsearch_discovery_zen_ping_unicast_hosts = {% for host in groups['tag_Function_logdb']  %}
{{ host }}:9300
{%- if loop.first %},{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to output a comma delimited list in jinja python template?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11974318/how-to-output-a-comma-delimited-list-in-jinja-python-template)

Comment: "this works" is not correct (or, only correct for two items) - please re-edit "this works for two items"

Comment: @gedge done, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's the solution that worked for me.  I discovered that tweeks200's solution only works for 2 loops.  This works regardless of the number of loops.  Thanks to everyone here for the help.

```
elasticsearch_discovery_zen_ping_unicast_hosts={% for host in groups['tag_Function_logdb']  %}
{{ host }}:9300
{%- if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get this working by putting the directive I wanted before loop and then using the `loop.first` and `-` whitespace control to format the comma separated list properly.

```
elasticsearch_discovery_zen_ping_unicast_hosts = {% for host in groups['tag_Function_logdb']  %}
{{ host }}:9300
{%- if loop.first %},{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: The check should be `if not loop.last` or it would not work for loop bigger than 2 elements.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can do it:

```
elasticsearch_discovery_zen_ping_unicast_hosts = &nbsp;

 {% for host in groups['tag_Function_logdb']  %}

    {{ host }}:9300

    {% if not groups['tag_Function_logdb'].last %}
, 
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks, making some progress.  The `elasticsearch_discovery_zen_ping_unicast_hosts = &nbsp;` is not being populated and instead just showing as text.  Should that be in part of the loop somehow?