# How to remove trailing whitespace from jinja template with multiple strings separated by spaces?

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2, trailing-whitespace

I am really struggling on this for some reason and cannot figure this out.  I've tried multiple variations with no luck.  Basically, I am injecting multiple LDAP endpoints into my nslcd.conf via Jinja2 templating and Ansible, however I am left with a trailing whitespace no matter what I do.  On some nodes it's causing the nslcd service to fail to load, so I'm trying to yank the whitespace but having horrible luck.  Any suggestions?  Here is the basic code -

```
uri = {% for host in ldap_hosts %}{{ ldap_protocol }}://{{ host }} {% endfor %}

base {{ ldap_base_dn }}
binddn {{ ldap_bind_dn }}
bindpw {{ ldap_bind_password }}
rootpwmoddn {{ ldap_bind_dn }}
```

Output -

```
uri = ldaps://ldaps.fake.domain.net ldaps://ldaps.alsofake.domain.net
base DC=something,DC=local
binddn CN=ldap_bind_user,OU=ServiceAccounts,OU=Groups,OU=Accounts,DC=something,DC=local
bindpw yoink
rootpwmoddn CN=ldap_bind_user,OU=ServiceAccounts,OU=Groups,OU=Accounts,DC=something,DC=local
```

What I am trying to get is -

`uri = ldaps://ldaps.fake.domain.net ldaps://ldaps.alsofake.domain.net`

not

`uri = ldaps://ldaps.fake.domain.net ldaps://ldaps.alsofake.domain.net`

I have tried every combination of `uri = {% for host in ldap_hosts %}{{ ldap_protocol }}://{{ host }} {% endfor %}` I can think of.

`{%- for host in ldap_hosts %} ... {%+ endfor -%}` - completely removes the new line and puts base up on the uri line

`{%+ for host in ldap_hosts -%} ... {%+ endfor %}` - looks normal but trailing whitespace still exists

`{% for host in ldap_hosts %} ... {%- endfor -%}` - removes newline and puts base on the uri line

`{%+ for host in ldap_hosts -%} ... {%+ endfor -%}` - removes newline and puts base on the uri line

`{%+ for host in ldap_hosts -%} ... ://{{ host }}{% endfor %}` - smashes both endpoints together instead

Basically any option I try either removes the newline and puts base on the uri line, or makes it look normal but I find a whitespace at the end.  Yes, I know there is a space in here - `://{{ host }} {%` but that is to separate the endpoints on the line so it has fallback options when one endpoint isn't responding.  This has been working fine for years up until literally this week when a device finally said "what is this whitespace" and failed the service instead.

**Update:**

`uri = {% for host in ldap_hosts %}{{ ldap_protocol }}://{{ host }}{% if not loop.last %} {% endif %}{% endfor %}` did the trick!  Thanks **JonSG**

Comment: Why do you use jinja2? It's just string concatenation. One of the simplest things, natively supported by python.

Comment: @Mikaelblomkvistsson Because we use Ansible to inject the endpoints based on the environment and site.  And each site and env has it's own definition of endpoints to be added to the hosts.  UAT uses different endpoints than commercial, and commercial has LDAP endpoints in each region and we add the 3 nearest to each.

Comment: Maybe: `uri = {% for host in ldap_hosts %}{{ ldap_protocol }}://{{ host }}{% if not loop.last %} {% endif %}{% endfor %}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to output a comma delimited list in jinja python template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11974318/how-to-output-a-comma-delimited-list-in-jinja-python-template) The `joiner` answer with a space rather than a comma looks even cleaner.

Comment: @JonSG That `if not loop.last` did the trick!  Thank you so much!  This has been driving me crazy and I ended up bandaiding it with another ansible task to sed out the trailing whitespaces.  This makes it much easier and doesn't waste another task cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minus and plus signs control both whitespaces and newlines. So, just move the space to the beginning of the line and use `{%- for ... %}` to eliminate the need to deal with the newlines and simply remove the leading space from the beginning of the loop:

```py
uri =  {%- for host in ldap_hosts %}{{ ldap_protocol }}://{{ host }}{% endfor %}

base {{ ldap_base_dn }}
binddn {{ ldap_bind_dn }}
bindpw {{ ldap_bind_password }}
rootpwmoddn {{ ldap_bind_dn }}
```

Alternatively, you can omit the loop and prepare the full line using `map`, `join`, and some regex to add the protocol prefix to each element of the list (you can also move the preparation out of the template by the way - to reduce the complexity or to reuse the value):

```py
uri = {{ ldap_hosts | map('regex_replace', '^(\\w)', ldap_protocol + '://\\1' | join(' ') }}
base {{ ldap_base_dn }}
binddn {{ ldap_bind_dn }}
bindpw {{ ldap_bind_password }}
rootpwmoddn {{ ldap_bind_dn }}
```

However, I'd prefer the first way as it looks cleaner (and probably wouldn't even cause the syntax errors if you don't trim the leading space).